# Why do we have to use InetSocketAddress to enter our port number for using ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java

why do we have to create an object of `InetSocketAddress`?

but for `ServerSocket` we just use `int` to enter port number

Example:

```
    try(
    ServerSocketChannel listener = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = listener.socket()
    ){

        serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2266));
        //we can't use serverSocket.bind(2266);

    }catch (IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to read the question correctly. One of your claims is “we just use `int` to enter port number” but then in your code you don't just use `int` but instead you use `InetSocketAddress` and claim that “we cannot use `int` to enter port number”. You seem to have a contradiction in the question itself.

Comment: we can't use `serverSocket.bind(2266)`, we have to wrap this port number by a `new InetSocketAddress(2266)` or in other word put this port number inside `new InetSocketAddress()` constructor WHY?

Comment: why do we have to use InetSocketAddress? why can't we just put our number in there like when we want to create a simple SocketServer

Comment: Good APIs are design for consistency, not for the smallest possible number of characters in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear.

`ServerSocket#bind()` establishes the ***local*** end of the connection.  If your system has more than one network adapter and/or more than one IP address, AND you wanted to connect the socket using a specific local adapter or IP address, then you would provide a complete `InetSocketAddress(host,port)` with both host and port, where the host part was one of your local IP addresses.

In the default case where you have only one IP address, or have more than one but don't care which one is used as the source, you can omit the host and just specify the port, as in your example.

The API is defined this way.  A TCP connection is *symmetrical*, and is defined by its two endpoints.  An endpoint is a pair (host,port).  This applies to BOTH ends of the connection.  Thus the `bind()` call takes an `InetSocketAddress` parameter. For convenience, `InetSocketAddress` will assume the default host that specifies "use any available interface" if you provide only a port.

The API designers *could* have added a `bind(int port)` method to build the `InetSocketAddress(port)` behind the scenes, but clearly didn't feel it was necessary.

Comment: this part: 
'The API is defined this way. It takes an InetSocketAddress parameter, and that parameter can contain just the port or a complete host/port'
my question is why the API is defined this way... and not just get a plain 'int' as it does for SocketServer(port)

Comment: @James The second part of the very sentence answers your question. The `InetSocketAddress` contains more than just the port. If you specify just the port, other attributes are set to their default values. The API is pretty simple and you have no reason to complain.

Comment: @James I updated my answer.  If you still want to know why you'll have to take it up with the designers of the API.

Comment: ok I assume the answer is the API designers felt it was necessary and anything otherwise wouldn't work the way they intended

Answer (score 0):

InetSocketAddress creates a socket address where the IP address is the **wildcard** address and the port number a specified value

wildcard is special IP address which can be used for binding. If you don't want to listen "everything" but maybe spesific IPs, say, 5.5.5.5 for example, you will be binded to that IP address but not others.

But without the IP part to it means any IP will be listened so pretty much no difference for this particular usage.